# How does String.Length work in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to know how the `String.Length` can count the characters number. 
If possible, a simple algorithm would be nice to explain it.

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't. The number of characters is stored as a field (`m_stringLength`, if it matters); `.Length` simply returns this value. In .NET, strings are not typically nul-terminated or similar. The more interesting question is "where is the string data stored" - which is complex; the `string` type is an exception to the usual rule, and the objects themselves have variable size; the character data is directly inside the `string` object (it is not the case that the `string` type has a pointer or reference to the character data; it **is** the character data, plus a length field).

Comment: We have a winner. I am not a fan of strings being a giant exception to the reference vs value rule myself.

Comment: @Gusdor it isn't an exception to that rule: it is a reference-type, plain and simple

Comment: and yet, strings are immutable due to their operator implementation.

Comment: @Gusdor lots of reference types are immutable; several value-types are mutable

Comment: `"it is not the case that the string type has a pointer or reference to the character data; it is the character data, plus a length field"`. Sir, I'm getting mixed messages.

Comment: @MarcGravell If it is a reference type then is it not a pointer referencing to somewhere?

Comment: @MarcGravell I can see `m_firstChar` field in reflector. and equals method compares using `char*` and the length of string. I suspect string is just wrapper over `char*` and `Length`. Am I wrong ? correct me pls

Comment: @Gusdor a `string` variable/field etc holds a reference to a `string` instance, yes; that is the case for any reference-type; what I mean is that *inside* the `string`, there is no reference/pointer; the `string` object is **just** the length and then the raw character data directly

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the field is a `char`, not a `char*`. The *relative offset of that `char` field* is used to mean "the start of the character data"; basically, any time you see `&this.m_firstChar`, that basically means "the value of `this` plus 4 bytes"

Comment: @abhitalks see my reply to Gusdor

Comment: My confusion is gone. Ta Marc

Comment: @MarcGravell I can't find what is that `4 bytes` Where does that 4 comes from. Size of char is 1 byte right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the length field comes before the data, and is an `int`, therefore `4` bytes.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah,.. thank you very much for clarification.. Can you pls refer some link to get to know internals. How do you know these..?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel mainly, "reflector" ;p

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Of course, the other way to learn this kind of stuff is to download [.Net Framework Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).  In this case, you'd want to look in this folder: PATH\RefSrc\Source\.Net\4.0\DEVDIV_TFS\Dev10\Releases\RTMRel\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\String.cs

Comment: @Brian but if you use the comments and variable names, *where's the challenge* ? :)

Answer (score 2):

`SystemString.Length` does not count characters, it stores the length.

There are two general ways of storing strings - characters+length, and characters+terminator. In .NET the first approach is used; in other languages, such as C, the second approach is used.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways to implement a string in a binary system:

1. Put a number indicating the length at the front (this is how [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does it).
2. Terminate the string with a special character. This is the 'C' style string.

For the first approach you can just take the number out of memory and return it. The second approach requires counting until the special character (NULL) is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET internally strings are stored as a NULL terminated character array with extra meta data like the length and whether or not the string contains any special characters. Because strings are immutable the new string created from an operation (ex: concatenation) has an updated length.

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx

Here's a basic string length function, if you had a null terminated character array and you wanted to find the length.

**EDIT** to clarify, character arrays CAN contain null or \0 character, but when you are representing that array as a null terminated string the string will end at the first null it reach. Another point is characters in .NET are UTF-16, but 'usually' when referring to null terminated strings you would be dealing with ASCII (1 8bit byte per character) and for the following example I'll use a byte[] array instead of char[] array to clarify that.

```
long length = 0;
foreach(var ch in byteArray) {
    if(ch == 0) break;
    length++;
}
```

Comment: No, no they aren't. Firstly, they aren't null-terminated; secondly, they aren't a `char[]` (which is how I would interpret "character array"). Example: `char[] chars = { 'a', (char)0, 'b', '\0', 'c' }; string s = new string(chars); Console.WriteLine(s.Length);` - displays `5`.

Comment: @MarcGravell - according to the link I posted they are internally stored as a null terminated character array ** the character array is null-terminated, as this means it can be passed directly to unmanaged functions without any copying being involved, assuming the inter-op specifies that the string should be marshalled as Unicode.  **

Comment: @MarcGravell - As for my example of a string length function. I thought I made it clear, that would be how to find the string length of a null terminated string specifically. If you passed your test char[] array to an API that uses null terminated strings (like KERNEL32.strlenA) you would get 1 as your result.

Comment: indeed, the example you give would give the length of a null-terminated sequence in a character array; the problem is, that is not really related (except tangentially) to the question of how `string.Length` works...

Comment: @MarcGravell - The OP was looking for a "simple algorithm", I provided that and elaborated the caveats related to it.